# Problem with the implementation of finding whether the area of a rectangle intersects another

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a method which returns true if
some part of the area covered by a rectangle is also part of another rectangle, false otherwise using the x and y coordinates along with the width and height.

Along with the code below, I've initialised the variables x,y,width and height which are attributes of the object BoundingBox

```java
public boolean intersects(BoundingBox box) {
    int boxx = getX();
    int boxy = getY();
    int boxw = getWidth();
    int boxh = getHeight();
    if ( box.getX()+ box.getWidth() < boxx || box.getY() + box.getHeight() < boxy || boxx+boxw < box.getX() || boxy + boxh < box.getY()) {
        if (boxw*boxh <= box.getWidth()*box.getHeight()) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }   
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I try to see if a rectangle with (x,y,width,height) = (20,0,1,20) intersects with the original rectangle I've set up as (10,10,10,10), I expected to see the result of false but the actual output is true?

Comment: Debugging time!

Comment: I think you need [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-two-rectangles-overlap/) + debugging :)

Comment: Ok you had your fun promoting those sites now lets get to work!!

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your for loop.

```
if (boxx > box.getX()+box.getWidth() || box.getX(0) > boxx) { 
    return false; 
}

if (boxy < box.getY()+box.getHeight() || box.getY() < boxy+boxh) { 
    return false; 
} 
return true;
```